# Where is documentation for Gradle's `test` block from Java plugin located?

Tags: gradle

As can be seen from the top of [documentation of class `org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html), test tasks can be configured using the following piece of code:

```
test {
    // configuration here. For example:
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

From usage of [method `useJUnitPlatform`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html#useJUnitPlatform--) we can assume that method `test` is called with a `Closure` which has an instance of aforementioned class `Test` as delegate.

In Gradle, there are other similar methods which take a `Closure`. For example, `afterEvaluate`. [Documentation of method `afterEvaluate`](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#afterEvaluate-groovy.lang.Closure-) is readily available in documentation of class `Project`. This is also [mentioned in the user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:project_evaluation):

> This example uses method `Project.afterEvaluate()` to add a closure which is executed after the project is evaluated.

Where is the documentation of method `test`? I could not find it. Or maybe this isn't a method in a class, but inserted via reflection into class `Project` at runtime or some similar DSL magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `test { ... }` in this case is not calling a method with name `test`. This block is a feature of the Gradle API called "Groovy dynamic task configuration block". Per [Gradle documentation version 6.1](https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/userguide/more_about_tasks.html):

> ```
> // Configure task using Groovy dynamic task configuration block
> myCopy {
>    from 'resources'
>    into 'target'
> }
> myCopy.include('**/*.txt', '**/*.xml', '**/*.properties')
> ```
>
> This works for *any* task. Task access is just a shortcut for the `tasks.named()` (Kotlin) or `tasks.getByName()` (Groovy) method. It is important to note that blocks used here are for *configuring* the task and are not evaluated when the task executes.

As such, per this shortcut convention, `test { ... }` block is used for configuring a task registered in the project – task with name `test` in this case.

Although nowadays I'd recommend using [Gradle's Configuration Avoidance API](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#task_configuration_avoidance) to configure a task lazily instead of eagerly:

```
project.tasks.named('test', Test).configure {
    it.useJunitPlatform()
}
```

See `getByName` replacement in the table ["Existing vs New API overview"](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html#sec:old_vs_new_configuration_api_overview).

Comment: jannis, thank you for taking time to write this answer. However, I'm not interested in explanations of `test { ... }` block. I'm interested in finding out if Gradle project has **documentation** of it.

Comment: Do you mean documentation of the 'test' task? https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html

Comment: The user guide for older versions includes a mention of this way of configuring tasks (legacy now - the current version has examples rewritten with the mentioned Configuration Avoidance API) - see Example 9: https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:configuring_tasks

Answer (score 3):

`test` in this context is not a method per se, but rather a task named `test`. To figure out what exactly is going on here requires diving into the internals of Gradle itself which is not part of any public documentation because well, it's not part of the public API.

The only way to figure exactly out what is going on is to debug Gradle during its execution. The easiest way to do that is to generate a plugin project via [`gradle init`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html). Write a simple Gradle build file such as (`build.gradle`; I am assuming you are using the Groovy DSL):

```
plugins {
    id("java")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Then write a basic [functional test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/test_kit.html) and start debugging. I was curious myself what is going and did just that.

In the following screenshot, you can see the stack trace in the bottom left corner. As you can see, there is *a lot* of methods called.

[image: debug of script]

There is a mixture of Groovy specific methods and Gradle specific methods. Digging further in, you will come to:

[image]

You can see here bottom right that the list of `objects` is:

1. `Project` (root project)
2. Extra properties
3. Extensions
4. Tasks

This aligns with what I mentioned earlier: Gradle will go out of its way to match to what is being asked for. This is also explained in the ["A Groovy Build Script Primer"](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/groovy_build_script_primer.html#groovy:properties) in official documentation (starting from "If the name is unqualified [...]").

Eventually, you will land in some of the public API methods:

[image]

`getByName` is part of [`NamedDomainObjectContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer.html#org.gradle.api.NamedDomainObjectContainer:getByName(java.lang.String)) which is documented. However, what actually implements that interface is not as you can see from the Javadoc [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectContainer.html). The implementation, from debugging, is [`DefaultTaskContainer`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v7.2.0/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/DefaultTaskContainer.java).

The rest I will leave to you as an exercise. Hopefully this gives you an idea as to what is going on behind the scenes.